# A valid delegate for IssuerSigningKeyResolver

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates

I'm having trouble setting up my TokenValidation Parameters. VS is telling me that in the delegate for ***IssuerSigningKeyResolver*** at "x.Id" that "'char' does not contain a definition for 'Id'".

In this case "certificates" is declared and loaded with Google certs thusly: -

```
        Byte[][] certBytes = getCertBytes(GOOGLE_CERTS);
        Dictionary<String, X509Certificate2> certificates = new Dictionary<String, X509Certificate2>();
        for (int i = 0; i < certBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes[i]);
            certificates.Add(certificate.Thumbprint, certificate);
        }


       TokenValidationParameters JWTparams = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateAudience = true, 
            ValidAudience = CLIENT_ID,
            ValidateIssuer = true, 
            ValidIssuers = VALID_ISSUERS,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (tokenString, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
            {
                return identifier.Select(x =>
                {
                    if (certificates.ContainsKey(x.Id.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        return new X509SecurityKey(certificates[x.Id.ToUpper()]);
                    }
                    return null;
                }).First(x => x != null);
            },
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };
```

I'm by no means a guru at C# so would appreciate the help with some code I copied. My "understanding" is the delegate receives "identifier" as a string so why Linq.Select is being used I am not sure because I'm, guessing it will just go through the string one char at a time?

The Docs say that "identifier" may be null but is ".First(x => x != null)" suppose to be handling successive calls?

"securityToken" has an Id but isn't appropriate anywhere else.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a valid and more logical/readable approach: -

```
IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
{
    return certificates
    .Where(x => x.Key.ToUpper() == kid.ToUpper())
    .Select(x => new X509SecurityKey(x.Value));
},
```

Comment: The `kid` is a base64url-encoded byte array, so when comparing it as a string, you should use case-sensitive comparison.